# C# - How to Deserialize XML with a List in a List

Tags: c#, xml

Here is the XML I am receiving as a response from a SOAP call:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Usage_Data Public="0">
    <Type_Data Primary="1">
        <Type_Reference>
            <ID type="WID">4fae289a7fe541b098ca9448e462ff6b</ID>
            <ID type="Communication_Usage_Type_ID">BUSINESS</ID>
        </Type_Reference>
    </Type_Data>
    <Use_For_Reference>
        <ID type="WID">7a232f5736a840a393b8ab43df7becd5</ID>
        <ID type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">BILLING</ID>
    </Use_For_Reference>
    <Use_For_Reference>
        <ID type="WID">b58a4a54e04c4e1f8fc32bfc3b1a77cf</ID>
        <ID type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">SHIPPING</ID>
    </Use_For_Reference>
    <Use_For_Reference>
        <ID type="WID">8f470e4f6ffd49638c80ea6b5443bddb</ID>
        <ID type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">REMIT</ID>
    </Use_For_Reference>
</Usage_Data>
```

I have used this to create a C# class so that I can deserialize the XML. The generated class is ugly and unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tweaked it enough to get it somewhat working. The big problem is with the "Use_For_Reference" elements. The "type" attribute in each of the "ID" elements is not being pulled into the deserialized classes.

```
[Serializable]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Usage_Data
{
    private Usage_DataType_Data type_DataField;
    private List<Usage_DataUse_For_ReferenceID> use_For_ReferenceField;
    private byte publicField;

    public Usage_DataType_Data Type_Data
    {
        get => type_DataField;
        set => type_DataField = value;
    }

    [XmlArrayItem("ID", typeof(Usage_DataUse_For_ReferenceID), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<Usage_DataUse_For_ReferenceID> Use_For_Reference
    {
        get => use_For_ReferenceField;
        set => use_For_ReferenceField = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public byte Public
    {
        get => publicField;
        set => publicField = value;
    }
}

[Serializable]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Usage_DataType_Data
{
    private Usage_DataType_DataID[] type_ReferenceField;
    private byte primaryField;

    [XmlArrayItem("ID", IsNullable = false)]
    public Usage_DataType_DataID[] Type_Reference
    {
        get => type_ReferenceField;
        set => type_ReferenceField = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public byte Primary
    {
        get => primaryField;
        set => primaryField = value;
    }
}

[Serializable]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Usage_DataType_DataID
{
    private string typeField;
    private string valueField;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type
    {
        get => typeField;
        set => typeField = value;
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value
    {
        get => valueField;
        set => valueField = value;
    }
}

[Serializable]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Usage_DataUse_For_ReferenceID
{
    private string typeField;
    private string valueField;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type
    {
        get => typeField;
        set => typeField = value;
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value
    {
        get => valueField;
        set => valueField = value;
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out how to get the "type" property populated from the XML deserialization. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just roll your own LINQ-to-XML solution?

Comment: My XML is actually much more complicated than what I'm showing above. I'm only showing the part that I'm having a problem with. I've never done LINQ-to-XML. Would it be difficult with this XML if the stuff I show is about 5 layers deep?

Comment: Can you please show your full XML? Maybe in pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
// using System.Xml.Serialization;
// XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UsageData));
// using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
// {
//    var test = (UsageData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
// }

[XmlRoot(ElementName="ID")]
public class ID { 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")] 
    public string Type { get; set; } 

    [XmlText] 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Type_Reference")]
public class TypeReference { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="ID")] 
    public List<ID> ID { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Type_Data")]
public class TypeData { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Type_Reference")] 
    public TypeReference TypeReference { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Primary")] 
    public int Primary { get; set; } 

    [XmlText] 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Use_For_Reference")]
public class UseForReference { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="ID")] 
    public List<ID> ID { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Usage_Data")]
public class UsageData { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Type_Data")] 
    public TypeData TypeData { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Use_For_Reference")] 
    public List<UseForReference> UseForReference { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Public")] 
    public int Public { get; set; } 

    [XmlText] 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

Using: https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp